# How to send a packet from device A, but make it seem as if the packet came from device B?

Tags: packet

I have two devices on my Wifi, a laptop running windows 7, 32-bit, and an iPhone 6 plus. How can I send a packet from my laptop to a target, but make it look as if (from the targets view) that the iPhone sent the packet? If I am wrong about how the packet system works, could you please point out my mistakes? Also, if this is on the wrong site, please point that out and I will fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on what you mean by look like. If the target is the other side of a NAT gateway it might not be able to tell. By comparison for TCP on local network you will need to fake the MAC address, the sender IP, and the sequence number.

Comment: I have no idea what framework you are using but at the highest level, you couldn't do what is specified. Package exchange is a two-way conversation - if you succeeded in sending the first packet then the response would go to the wrong device (ie where the destination thought the data was coming from). If you want to make device A look like device B then you might want to re-phrase your question.

Comment: @Mike it is perfectly achievable if you can predict or intercept the response. Or the protocol does not rely on the response.

Comment: @user1937198 How would I fake the MAC, IP, and sequence number? And also, (sorry) what is the sequence number?

Comment: You will need to know what protocol you are trying to fake. You fill probably need to write raw packets to the network device so start by learning how to construct network layer packets in your chosen os. You will need to understand the network stack in some detail which is beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question.